# Why can't I type "|" in the codecademy Command Line course?

Tags: command-line-tool

I am 55% into the Command Line course on Codecademy but, I can't type "|".
I'm trying to do

```
cat volcanoes.txt | wc
```

And the | doesn't show and when I try to copy+paste it in only shows a ^V instead of the |. Please help

Comment: Can you type it using the key on your keyboard (right above enter)?

Comment: Also try `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C/V`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan but none of these worked either

Comment: Where are you copying and pasting from?

Comment: I have tried copy pasting from the search bar, websites, documents and anywhere else I can type it in basically.

Comment: In most terminals you use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V` to paste.

Comment: Nope, but do you think there is a way to change key bindings on Windows 7?

Comment: I am able to type the `|` (pipe character) just using my keyboard. I don't think copying/pasting is supported in the command line course. Do you not have that key on your keyboard?

Comment: I do and it doesn't work either.

Comment: You may want to email codecademy support then.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing alt + 124 on the numpad.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to US keyboard layout. Last key in ASDF row (just next to Enter) should print "|" when pressed in combination with Shift.

It worked for me in Codecademy command line console.